# Unable to connect to internet after setting up ZAP configuration on Android using a hotspot connection

Tags: mobile, owasp, zap

I am trying to configure ZAP on an Android device using a hotspot connection opened on another Android device.

I followed the setup instructions available here: https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/webapp/zapandroidsetup I also tried indicating my laptop's ip address as local proxy when configuring ZAP on the laptop, plus tried with different ports.

Connecting to hotspot network without any proxy configuration works fine. But, as soon as I select Manual proxy settings and enter my laptop's ip address and port that ZAP is listening on and restart the wifi connection on the test device, the connectivity status goes from "Connecting" to "Checking the quality of your internet connection" and then it finally changes to "Internet may not be available" (and it isn't).

Am I doing something wrong? Should I be configuring something more? Thanks.

Comment: Is your laptop using the same hotspot?

Comment: @kingthorin Yes.

Comment: Does the laptop have a local firewall? Win? Linux?

Comment: No, no local firewall and it's on Windows 10.

Comment: Apologies, windows defender firewall is actually enabled. I have also added a couple of inbound and outbound rules just now to make sure ZAP isn't blocked.